# Poor Out of Sample Performance in h2o randomForest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, h2o

I am running a randomForest model using h2o in R. The exercise is a binary classification problem in which I have approx. 5x as many ‘1’s as ‘0’s.

Because the dataset is a time series (approx. 50k observations), I am using a growing window validation scheme as opposed to the typical CV schemes used in most ML cases. For each step I train the model on 60% of the data available up to that time point and then hold out the remaining 40% to be split equally between the validation frame and the testing data.

I am getting extremely poor performance in both my hold out validation data and test data which suggests that I am overfitting to the training dataset. If anyone can spot any obvious, glaring errors in how I am setting up my model and the hyper parameter search I’d really appreciate some pointers. It may be that I simply have in sufficient number of features (n = 27) to adequately capture the response, but I would like to rule out incorrect model specification first.

Here is the specification of my model and the hyper-parameter grid search.

```
# create feature names
y <- "Response"
x <- setdiff(names(gwWF1_train[, -c(1:3)]), y)

# turn training set into h2o object
gwWF1_train.h2o <- as.h2o(gwWF1_train[, -c(1:3)])

# turn validation set into h2o object
gwWF1_valid.h2o <- as.h2o(gwWF1_valid[, -c(1:3)])

# hyperparameter grid
hyper_grid.h2o <- list(
  ntrees      = seq(50, 1000, by = 50),
  mtries      = seq(2, 10, by = 1),
  max_depth   = seq(2, 10, by = 1),
  min_rows    = seq(5, 15, by = 1),
  nbins       = seq(5, 40, by = 5),
  sample_rate = c(.55, .632, .75)
)

# random grid search criteria
search_criteria <- list(
  strategy = "RandomDiscrete",
  stopping_metric = "auc",
  stopping_tolerance = 0.005,
  stopping_rounds = 20,
  max_runtime_secs = 5*60
  )

# build grid search 
random_grid <- h2o.grid(
  algorithm = "randomForest",
  grid_id = "rf_grid",
  x = x, 
  y = y, 
  seed = 29,
  balance_classes = TRUE,
  training_frame = gwWF1_train.h2o,
  validation_frame = gwWF1_valid.h2o,
  hyper_params = hyper_grid.h2o,
  search_criteria = search_criteria
  )
  
# collect the results and sort by our model performance metric of choice
grid_perf <- h2o.getGrid(
  grid_id = "rf_grid", 
  sort_by = "auc", 
  decreasing = TRUE
  )
print(grid_perf)
```

Here is the performance on the training and validation frames

```
Model Details:
==============

H2OBinomialModel: drf
Model ID:  rf_grid_model_14 
Model Summary: 
  number_of_trees number_of_internal_trees model_size_in_bytes min_depth max_depth mean_depth min_leaves max_leaves mean_leaves
1             100                      100              224183        10        10   10.00000         99        272   173.86000


H2OBinomialMetrics: drf
** Reported on training data. **
** Metrics reported on Out-Of-Bag training samples **

MSE:  0.1154841
RMSE:  0.3398295
LogLoss:  0.3836627
Mean Per-Class Error:  0.3434005
AUC:  0.716039
AUCPR:  0.3877677
Gini:  0.432078
R^2:  0.08126146

Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted) for F1-optimal threshold:
           0    1    Error         Rate
0      12089 2009 0.142502  =2009/14098
1       1327 1111 0.544299   =1327/2438
Totals 13416 3120 0.201742  =3336/16536

Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
                        metric threshold        value idx
1                       max f1  0.182031     0.399784 175
2                       max f2  0.133141     0.498254 264
3                 max f0point5  0.229674     0.437443 119
4                 max accuracy  0.263718     0.863147  94
5                max precision  0.705162     1.000000   0
6                   max recall  0.019641     1.000000 396
7              max specificity  0.705162     1.000000   0
8             max absolute_mcc  0.209525     0.298843 139
9   max min_per_class_accuracy  0.153280     0.651354 225
10 max mean_per_class_accuracy  0.174269     0.661033 188
11                     max tns  0.705162 14098.000000   0
12                     max fns  0.705162  2437.000000   0
13                     max fps  0.010717 14098.000000 399
14                     max tps  0.019641  2438.000000 396
15                     max tnr  0.705162     1.000000   0
16                     max fnr  0.705162     0.999590   0
17                     max fpr  0.010717     1.000000 399
18                     max tpr  0.019641     1.000000 396

Gains/Lift Table: Extract with `h2o.gainsLift(<model>, <data>)` or `h2o.gainsLift(<model>, valid=<T/F>, xval=<T/F>)`
H2OBinomialMetrics: drf
** Reported on validation data. **

MSE:  0.1340771
RMSE:  0.3661654
LogLoss:  0.4422115
Mean Per-Class Error:  0.5
AUC:  0.5295048
AUCPR:  0.1770512
Gini:  0.05900952
R^2:  -0.006636504

Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted) for F1-optimal threshold:
       0     1    Error          Rate
0      0 13220 1.000000  =13220/13220
1      0  2485 0.000000       =0/2485
Totals 0 15705 0.841770  =13220/15705

Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
                        metric threshold        value idx
1                       max f1  0.025167     0.273227 399
2                       max f2  0.025167     0.484500 399
3                 max f0point5  0.161209     0.203459 140
4                 max accuracy  0.291947     0.841770   1
5                max precision  0.291947     0.500000   1
6                   max recall  0.025167     1.000000 399
7              max specificity  0.302964     0.999924   0
8             max absolute_mcc  0.178262     0.056716 103
9   max min_per_class_accuracy  0.133292     0.525553 215
10 max mean_per_class_accuracy  0.140828     0.529093 195
11                     max tns  0.302964 13219.000000   0
12                     max fns  0.302964  2485.000000   0
13                     max fps  0.030503 13220.000000 398
14                     max tps  0.025167  2485.000000 399
15                     max tnr  0.302964     0.999924   0
16                     max fnr  0.302964     1.000000   0
17                     max fpr  0.030503     1.000000 398
18                     max tpr  0.025167     1.000000 399

Gains/Lift Table: Extract with `h2o.gainsLift(<model>, <data>)` or `h2o.gainsLift(<model>, valid=<T/F>, xval=<T/F>)`
```

And here is the performance on the testing data

```
H2OBinomialMetrics: drf

MSE:  0.1293883
RMSE:  0.3597059
LogLoss:  0.4274263
Mean Per-Class Error:  0.4719334
AUC:  0.530868
AUCPR:  0.1588326
Gini:  0.06173602
R^2:  -0.001929629

Confusion Matrix (vertical: actual; across: predicted) for F1-optimal threshold:
          0     1    Error          Rate
0      4321 12888 0.748910  =12888/17209
1       603  2490 0.194956     =603/3093
Totals 4924 15378 0.664516  =13491/20302

Maximum Metrics: Maximum metrics at their respective thresholds
                        metric threshold        value idx
1                       max f1  0.128344     0.269612 283
2                       max f2  0.084278     0.473644 380
3                 max f0point5  0.140284     0.194700 248
4                 max accuracy  0.313605     0.847601   1
5                max precision  0.313605     0.333333   1
6                   max recall  0.050387     1.000000 399
7              max specificity  0.316369     0.999884   0
8             max absolute_mcc  0.128344     0.047063 283
9   max min_per_class_accuracy  0.152158     0.522793 210
10 max mean_per_class_accuracy  0.140284     0.531315 248
11                     max tns  0.316369 17207.000000   0
12                     max fns  0.316369  3093.000000   0
13                     max fps  0.062918 17209.000000 398
14                     max tps  0.050387  3093.000000 399
15                     max tnr  0.316369     0.999884   0
16                     max fnr  0.316369     1.000000   0
17                     max fpr  0.062918     1.000000 398
18                     max tpr  0.050387     1.000000 399

Gains/Lift Table: Extract with `h2o.gainsLift(<model>, <data>)` or `h2o.gainsLift(<model>, valid=<T/F>, xval=<T/F>)`
```

Comment: How are you converting the probabilities output by the model into binary classifications?

Comment: Is this a classification problem? If yes, what do MSE, RMSE, and R^2 have to do here?

Comment: My understanding is that h2o.predict() assigns the model out out based on a threshold which is applied to the probability of scoring 1. The probability is chosen to maximise the F1 score.

Comment: yes it is a classification problem. MSE etc are not used in model selection via grid search I have specified using AUC. These quantities are returned by the model regardless. I assume they can simply be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post a list of all built models and their performances? The best one has  a depth 10, it would be useful to know what other hyperparameters were explored.

You max runtime is only 5 minutes, it is possible most of the hyperparameter space was not explored. Lets see what other models were build.

Comment: Thanks after many days of playing with the h2o package Ive seen that as you hypothesised 5 mins run time was much too short. Running for several hours leads to much more robust estimation comparing IS and OOS AUC.